# Stats about server side languages, server technologies

Tags: web-server

where to find updated stats about what is the web using as servers (Windows Servers, *Nix/Apache etc) and what are the most popular (with stats and numbers) technologies used for server side programming (php vs asp.net vs python...) and data storing (sqlserver vs mysql...)?

Any source appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NETCRAFT!](http://news.netcraft.com/)

btw, statistics are dead - netcraft confirms it!

Answer (score 0):

The [tiobe](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) index shows current popularity of programming languages. Whether the results its gives are accurate or just an mere indication is up for debate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay for the data, firms like [IDC](http://www.idc.com/), [Gartner](http://www.gartner.com) and [Forrester](http://www.forrester.com) do research on these types of things all the time. You can even purchase subscriptions to get their latest reports/etc. CIOs eat their fancy quadrant graphs and stuff up too.

Answer (score 0):

[W3Techs](http://w3techs.com/) has these statistics (except databases).